# Rails 5.1.4: Locale is being replaced by a duplicate path entry after doing an insertion into a database or just logging into the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue after setting `l18n locale` (:en and :es) in my app.
What's happening is that when I'm trying to insert a new record into the database, it changes the current locale to the current path, for example:

I have a Suggestion model and the path will be:

```
localhost:3000/es/suggestions
```

or

```
localhost:3000/es/suggestions
```

After I did an insert into the db, it becomes:

```
localhost:3000/**suggestions**/suggestions
```

so, the locale is being replaced.

The same happens when I'm trying to log into the app:

```
localhost:3000/**dashboard**/dashboard
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

scope '(:locale)' do
  get 'emp_management/index'

  get 'emp_management/salary'

  get 'goal/index'

  get 'goal/show'

  get 'goal/edit'

  get 'goal/create'

  get 'goal/destroy'

  get 'dataloader/index'

  get 'promotion/index'

  get 'metrics/index'

  get 'metrics/show'

  get 'course_lists/assigned'

  get 'course_lists/completed'

  get 'course_lists/assignments_completed'  

  get 'charts/suggestions_ideas_insights'

  get 'charts/suggestions_ideas_insights_1'

  get 'charts/platform_statistics'

  get 'charts/hr_statistics'

  get 'charts/courses_statistics'

  get 'charts/courses_insights'

  get 'charts/team_kpi'

  get 'charts/support'

  get 'charts/sales'

  get 'charts/marketing'

  get 'charts/basic_statistics'

  get 'charts/admin_stats'

  get 'charts/ed_insights'

  get 'charts/salary_insights'

  get 'reports/user_stats'

  get 'reports/account_stats'

  get 'reports/kpi_report'

  get 'reports/team_kpi'

  get 'performance_reviews/help'

  get 'performance_reviews/sent_for_approval'

  get 'performance_reviews/my_approval'

  get 'performance_reviews/approved'

  get 'performance_reviews/final_approval'

  get 'performance_reviews/reviews_approved'

  get 'reports/platform_statistics'

  get "suggestions/new_suggestion" => 'suggestions#new_suggestion', :as => :new_suggestion

  get :send_notification_mail, to: 'course_list_assignments#send_notification_mail', as: :send_notification_mail

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  root 'home#index'

  resources :users
  resources :courses
  resources :posts
  resources :dashboard
  resources :ideas do
    member do
        put "upvote" => "ideas#upvote"
        put "downvote" => "ideas#downvote"
    end
  end
  resources :performance_reviews do
    resources :goals
    resources :manager_comments
    member do
            patch :calculate
            patch :approve
            patch :reject
            patch :send_for_approval
            patch :read_approved
            patch :read_rejected
        end
  end   
  resources :suggestions
  resources :reports
  resources :course_list_assignments do
    member do
            patch :complete
        end
  end
  resources :charts
  resources :course_lists do
    member do
            patch :complete
            patch :read_all
        end
    get 'assign'
    resources :courses do
        member do
            patch :complete
        end
    end
  end

  resources :metrics do
    collection { post :import }
  end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }, :path => 'u'
end 
end
```

application controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
include Pundit
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :set_locale

helper_method :mobile?

private

def mobile? # has to be in here because it has access to "request"
  request.user_agent =~ /\b(Android|iPhone|iPad|Windows Phone|Opera 
Mobi|Kindle|BackBerry|PlayBook)\b/i
end

def set_locale
 I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
 # current_user.locale
 # request.subdomain
 # request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]
 # request.remote_ip
 end

 def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale  }
 end

 end
```

application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'
require 'csv'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Smartteamapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
  # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
config.load_defaults 5.1

I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
I18n.config.available_locales = :es
config.i18n.default_locale = :en

# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {

    :address    => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :domain     => 'mail.google.com',
    :port       => '587',
    :user_name  => '########@gmail.com', #ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
    :password   => '#######', #ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication   => 'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto   => true
}
end
end
```

Could you please help to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after changing:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
```

to

```
 scope '(/:locale)' do
```

I've also took these two lines out of the locale's scope in routes.rb to make sure the user can log in and log out with no issues:

```
root 'home#index'
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }, :path => 'u'
```